# docusignapi usefinfo api doesn't return attributes

Tags: c#, docusignapi

From the userinfo API, GET /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/users/{userId}/profile, this is not returning attributes like  company name,title
api url:

https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx/users/xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx/profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This endpoint (/profile) is only meant to get the profile image.

Either do a GET on the user directly to get basic information:

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/users/users/get/

Or do a /settings/ call to get user settings:

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/users/users/getsettings/

Comment: I want to extract user company name and title, but none of them give that as a output. Could you please suggest which one I should use to get the company name and title attributes of user?

Comment: Well, there are two things - the account name, and the user own information where they say what is their company name. These may or may not be the same. Most users don't update their company name. Which one did you mean? mostly it's the account name that people are asking about.